# Elastic search : [Oddball] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [1m], time since start [1m]

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Kibana is unable to load the data from elasticsearch. I could see the below log in the elasticsearch. I am using elasticsearch version 1.4.2. Is this something related to load? Could anyone please help me?

[2015-11-05 22:39:58,505][DEBUG][action.bulk              ] [Oddball] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [1m], time since start [1m]

Answer (score 0):

elastic search by default runs at http://localhost:9200
make sure you have proper URL in kibana.ymal

```
<pre>
    # Kibana is served by a back end server. This controls which port to use.
    port: 5601

    # The host to bind the server to.
    #host: example.com

    # The Elastic search instance to use for all your queries.
    elasticsearch_url: "http://localhost:9200"
</pre>
```

Aslo in elastic search config elasticsearch.yaml provide cluster name and http.cors.allow-origin.

```
<pre>
    # Cluster name identifies your cluster for auto-discovery. If you're running
    # multiple clusters on the same network, make sure you're using unique names.
    #
    cluster.name: elasticsearch

    http.cors.allow-origin: "/.*/"
</pre>
```

Comment: Hi Jitendra, Thank you for your reply. The cluster name is unique. Logstash. kibana and elasticsearch are running since almost a year and it got stopped immediately from last few days with the above error. Please let me know if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this by setting up a new node for Elasticsearch and clearing the unassigned shards by setting the replica to 0.